# UIScrollView with Button. Button to Highlight when touched, and still scroll the scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have some UIButtons within a UIScrollView. I want to highlight when touched, but still scroll if dragged.

I do not want to delay the button touches. However, as soon as the scroll view detects a drag/scroll, I want to cancel the UIButton touch and proceed with the scrolling of the UIScrollView.

I have included the following...

```
_scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

...but (obviously) the button touch does not cancel when dragged. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can implement this functionality?

This is very similar to the question asked here at:

> [iOS UIScrollView cancel UIButton touch on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819036/ios-uiscrollview-cancel-uibutton-touch-on-scroll)

But I don't understand the answer as I'm a fairly new developer.
more help on the answer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

His answer means:

You should create a subclass of UIScrollView, and override touchesShouldCancelInContentView.

For each Button :"show highlight effect for UIControlEventTouchDown." mean:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onTouchDownBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Not sure the answer works as you want, I just explain the answer.

Comment: Ive tried this with `-(void )onTouchDownBtn{
    self.dashboard.highlighted = YES;}` but it still doesn't work how i'd like it to

Comment: What is 'self.dashboard'? And what happen now? UIScrollView can scroll? Pls explain more about your situation.

Comment: For the button, try self.dashboard.selected = YES;

Comment: Tried that too I'm afraid.

Comment: maybe you should show more code. So someone can help you,